# File sharing on android device

Tags: android, file

I am doing an application with android studio.
I want the user to be able to put files in my app and the access it when using my app.

Something like itunes with apple devices but for an android device.
to be more clear I was using this with apple:

```
    paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    pathe = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
```

I don't know where and how the user put files and how to access it in my code. Is this possible? Is Android File Transfer doing it?

Comment: This is not a simple question and really there's no a method that automagically do this. Is a really complex task. You can start by looking at the Google Play Services functions and maybe one of those will help you.

Comment: Yes, it is. What have you tried? Have you thought any protocol? We need a more specific question

Comment: Put files? inside the apk? downloading it from a server? transfering from a PC?

Comment: for the moment nothing because I don't know what I can use. I want to put a .mp4 in my application and than use it as a texture.  Something like itunes do for ipad or iphones.

Comment: transfering from a PC